# I need to Use my exported JSON in HTML

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, json, html

Hi I am trying to learn new things in LWC ,, kindly help me out for this.
Scenario : I ahve a JSON .js file which is i have imported in the JS file and trying to use it in the HTML for my for:each iteration,,,
for:each iterator should iterate over the Complete JSON file and print the same number of lightning icon.
below is my code:

```
JSON.js file
const OCStat = (() => {
    return {
        COCStat: [
               {
                "CDATE":"07/07/2020",
                "LDATE":"07/09/2020",
                "Acciuy #":"jngg",
                "Myweyru":"hggfhfb"
              },
            {
                "CDATE":"07/07/2020",
                "LDATE":"07/09/2020",
                "Acciuy #":"jngg",
                "Myweyru":"hggfhfb"
            },
            {
                "CDATE":"07/07/2020",
                "LDATE":"07/09/2020",
                "Acciuy #":"jngg",
                "Myweyru":"hggfhfb"
            }
        ]
    }
});

export default OCStat;
```

JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import cOJSON from './OCStatJSON.js';

export default class COSTat extends LightningElement {

    @track cOHTs = cOJSON();
    @track cOHTs1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.cOHTs));
    
}
```

HTML file:

```
<template for:each={cOHTs1} for:item='cdateObj'>
                    <tr  key={cdateObj.CDATE}>
                        <td>
                            <div >
                                <lightning-button-icon '>
                                </lightning-button-icon>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
  </template>
```

error i am getting:

```
Error :  [t[xe] is not a function]
```

Kindly help me out for this ...Thanks'

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the top-level element in your JSON:

```
<template for:each={cOHTs1.COCStat} for:item="cdateObj">
```